# Trying to align 3 images and 3 texts on the same line with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align the 3 li items, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried different options of flexbox but nothing is making the lines of text move up, i've tried putting them in

tags but that just increases the gap.

I'd also like to know if it's possible to 'push' the discount section without adding such a big margin like I have done? I feel the margin isn't necessary?

Any help is really appreciated.

[image: What I want it to look like]
[image: What it currently looks like]

```
 <!-- DISCOUNT SECTION -->
        <section class="section3">
          <div class="section3wrap">
            <div class="section3text"> 
                <h2>Pay now and get</br> a 25% <span class="yellow-text">Discount</span></h2>
                <div class="test">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/check-icon.png">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<li>
                        <li><img src="img/check-icon.png">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                        <li><img src="img/check-icon.png">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a class="site-btn2">Join the Gym</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>

.section3 {
background-image: url("img/add-bg.jpg");
height: 600px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: top center;
}

.section3wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 250px;
}

.section3text {
    color: white;
}

.section3text li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.test {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: ;

}
```

Comment: Can anyone else help?

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

Make your `li` element a `display: flex; align-items: center;`, and surround the images with a `div`. Inline elements, like images, sometimes can act a bit different when aligning it to the text.

Comment: This partly fixed the problem. The text does line with the images, but now the images and text are not underneath the letter 'a' as seen in the first picture...any idea?

Comment: @LeeHoward maybe your code has some paddings/margins on the left on the `ul` or the `li`'s inherited by any generic element

Answer (score 0):

**Add extra css**

```
.test ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px
}

.section3text li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
}
.section3text li img{
margin-right:8px;
}
```

Comment: Now wat problem r u facing

Comment: the text is aligned correctly, but the 3 images are not underneath the letter 'a' like the first picture

Comment: add vertical align:middle css to image

Comment: to .section3? I just added it and nothing changed ;/

Comment: .section3text li img{
margin-right:8px;text-align:center;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206138/discussion-between-lee-howard-and-venkatramanan).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u r expecting:

```css
.section3 {
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff");
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
}

.section3wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
}

.section3text {
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.test ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.section3text li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:4px;
  line-height:15px;
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
}
.section3text img {
  padding:4px;
}

.test {
  display: flex;

}
.site-btn2{
background-color:yellow;
width:100px;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
line-height:40px;
color:black;
border-radius:3px;

}
```

```html
<section class="section3">
    <div class="section3wrap">
    
  <div class="section3text">

</div>
      <div class="section3text">
        <h2>Pay now and get<br> a 25% <span class="yellow-text">Discount</span></h2>
        <div class="test">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/12x12/fff/fff">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </li>
            <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/12x12/fff/fff">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/12x12/fff/fff">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="site-btn2">Join the Gym</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
```